# EJB+Postges+JSF Не работает приложение. Проблемы с транзакциями

Tags: postgresql, jsf, ejb, transaction

**Всем Добрый день !
Очень нужна помощь! Не могу разобраться, почему приложение валится. 
Подскажите, в чём может быть проблема.**

Для меня область совсем новая и незнакомая.

Было принято решение реализовать систему тестирования знаний на Postgresql + EJB + JSF.
ОРМ - EclipseLink, Управление транзакциями - CMT.
Сервер приложений GlassFish 4.1 
Пул соединений с БД (в качестве эксперимента 900 соединений, было 32). Пул EJB (600 шт, было 60 )
Таймаут транзакции 120 сек.

Приложение написано, но апробацию не проходит: сыпятся разного рода ошибки при минимальной нагрузке (около 10 человек). Большей частью связанные с транзакциями.

Например:

1. JTS5067: Unexpected error occurred in commit
   org.postgresql.xa.PGXAException: Not implemented: 2nd phase commit must be issued using an idle connection
2. A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB TryFacade
3. javax.ejb.EJBException: Unable to complete container-managed transaction.
   Caused by: javax.transaction.SystemException: org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: jts.exception_on_resource_operation  vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No
4. java.lang.RuntimeException: Got exception during XAResource.end: org.postgresql.xa.PGXAException: tried to call end without corresponding start call
5. Session event listener threw exception
   java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
6. A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB TryFacade
7. javax.ejb.EJBException: Transaction aborted
8. JTS5041: The resource manager is doing work outside a global transaction
   org.postgresql.xa.PGXAException: Error disabling autocommit
9. Постоянные DeadLock в БД

**Описание приложения (сорри за многословие).**

Архитектура проекта следующая 
(сформирована автоматически maven в NetBeans,
единственное, что изменено - это сделана связь между web проектом и EJB для доступа из ManagedBean к SessionBean):

1. MainProj(содержит всё нижеследующие модули)
2. EARProj (Модуль сборки)
3. EJBProj (EJB Модуль)
4. WEBProj (JSF Модуль)

Структура БД примерно такая:

1. Таблица вопросов
2. Таблица ответов (эталоны)
3. Таблица вопросов на конкретную попытку
4. Таблица ответов (вариант студента)
5. Таблица попыток

Структура EJB слоя:

1. Entity
2. StateLess FacadeBean

Структура WEB слоя

1. ManagedBean (все SessionScoped)
2. Страницы

Для каждого фасадного бина в веб слое есть свой контроллер (ManagedBean). Все методы фасадных бинов продублированы в контроллерах и при работе с веб слоем взаимодействуют между собой только контроллеры по средством CDI (они уже сами идут к своему фасаду ... и дальше в БД).

Логика работы приложения следующая:

1. студент попадает на страницу информации о тесте (настройки, доступ к статистике по каждой попытке, кнопка приступить)
2. При входе в тест идёт проверка наличие вопросов (select count...)
3. Если всё норм - из "контроллера попытки" в "фасаде попытки" (TryFacade) вызывается метод в котором в транзакции создаётся попытка и набираются вопросы в БД (в этом методе вызывается QuestionFacade для набора вопросов). Всё обёрнуто в try-Catch и куча проверок где идёт установка RollBack в случае ошибки.

4 Всё норм - вызывается метод для случайного выбора вопроса из набора.

5 Предоставляется вопрос (содержимое вопроса и вариантов ответа достаётся из базы отдельными запросами)

6 человек выбирает вариант ответа и нажимает на кнопку "ответить" (здесь идёт валидация данных клиента и тд)

7. Из "контроллера попытки" вызывается "контроллер вопроса" и его метод проверки правильности ответа (а там вызывается метод "контроллера ответа" для сравнения всех вариантов ответа с эталонами).
8. После проверки вызывается метод "контроллера вопроса", который уже в "фасаде" в транзакции пишет результаты в БД.
9. Идёт поиск следующего вопроса.

10 и т.д.

Все данные хранятся в сессии в соответствующих контроллерах. При выходе из процесса тестирования сессия и кэш EJB очищается для освобождения ресурсов.

23.10.2016.

вот файл персистентности:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="ru.rgups.ui.testSys_JTest-ejb_ejb_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/__DbConn</jta-data-source
    <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="none"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="SunAS9"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jtaDataSource" value="jdbc/__PGDbConn"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>`
```

конфиг источника данны (источник настроен как JDBC Pool) 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не совсем понял про примеры инъекций ejb и инъекций ентити манагера.
У нас инъекции entity man идут через CDI (@inject) в backing bean.
Инъекции ejb делаются стандартно: @EJB но уже в фасадных бинах.

```
@Stateless
public class TryFacade extends AbstractFacade<Try> {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "JTest-ejb_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU")
    private EntityManager em;
    @EJB
    private TryQuestionFacade tryQuestionF;
    .
    .
    .
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.SUPPORTS)
    public Try findByID(Integer studId) {
        try {
            if (studId != null) {
                Try sst = em.createNamedQuery("Try.findByIdz", Try.class)
                        .setParameter("idz", studId)
                        .getSingleResult();
                return sst;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
        return null;
    }
    .
    .
    .

@Named("tryController")
@SessionScoped
public class TryController implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    private TryFacade ejbFacade;

    .
    .
    .
    public Try getTryByIdz(Integer id) {
        if (id != null) {
            selected=getFacade().findByID(id);
            return getSelected();
        }
        return null;
    }

    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: Привели бы конфиг источника данных, модуля персистентности, инъекций ентити манагера, ежб, кусок программы, в котором видно вызов персистентных функций.

Comment: @Sergey, добрый день, добавил интересующую вас информацию.

Comment: А что в конфиге персистент-юнит `ru.rgups.ui.testSys_JTest-ejb_ejb_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU`. а в аннотации `JTest-ejb_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU` разве они не должны совпадать? А название пула в конфигурации сервера и в конфиге персистентности? В принципе они конечно могут различаться наверное, но тоже стоит уточнить, куда ведёт `jdbc/__DbConn` на самом деле.

Comment: И ещё посмотреть документацию Postgres насчёт этих хитрых транзакций двухфазных.  `PREPARE TARNSACTION` отвечает за двухфазные транзакции, и по умолчанию какое-то малое их количество. При большой нагрузке всем не хватает. Параметр `max_prepared_transactions` в `postgresql.conf`.

Comment: Другой вариант - переключиться на обычный датасоурс (без XA). XA нужен при участии в транзакции сразу нескольких датасоурсов (баз данных, очередей сообщений). Да и то при некоторых обстоятельствах и это можно обойти.

Comment: И сервер приложений. Когда выпустили 4 версию, то оракул сразу заявил, что не собирается его поддерживать патчами. Посмотрите http://www.payara.fish/ Это тот же глассфиш, только кто-то пытается его латать.

Comment: @Sergey Разница в наименованиях - это пой косяк ( я здесь редактировал, чтобы улучшить читаемость ))  По поводу PREPARE TARNSACTION Вы правы: параметр max_prepared_transactions вообще изначально стоял 0 - выключен. Мы этот параметр раньше выставили на 60. Но с ним не совсем ясно .... : через эти транзакции идут все транзакционные вызовы к БД или только какие-то определённые (типа вызов хранимых процедур). По поводу Glassfish - сразу стали паяру юзать: в Glassfish не работает админка в контексте создания пулов коннектов ))) - поэтому нашли паяру.

Comment: Эти транзакции работают со всеми вызовами, в которых они используются будь то процедуры или обычные запросы. Это специальные транзакции для поддержки распределённых транзакций. Когда несколько баз участвуют  в одной распределённой транзакции, то для каждой их них применяется двух-фазная транзакция. Какого-либо стандарта для таких транзакций не существует. В postgrese двух-фазные транзакции реализованы этими вот PREPARED TRANSACTION. PGXADatasource использует только их. Если они отключены на сервере, то и получается ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

Всем добрый день !

Делюсь новостями: последнюю ошибку `java.lang.IllegalStateException: state.isBusy() : false` и все с ней связанные (типа transaction aborted) порешали.

Как я понял у сервера Glassfish 4.1.1 есть нерешённый баг, из-за которого возникает конфликт потоков при обращении к транзакционным методам в фасадных бинах (если ошибаюсь и у кого-то всё крутится на этом серваке без проблем - отпишитесь, расскажите, как у вас всё организовано).
Поэтому проблему порешали переходом на WyldFly 10.01, где всё заработало так, как и планировалось и стабильно.

Конечно переделали и приложение: перешли на `viewScoped` вместо `Session` там, где это было критично в контексте потокобезопасности в JSF. Разделили методы, которые могли асинхронно вызываться разными сервисами (оттестили это на Glassfish - не помогло: ошибки продолжали сыпаться в том же количестве, а на WyldFly с тем же JDBC драйвером постгреса всё пошло нормально).

Всем спасибо за помощь!

Данный вопрос я не закрываю, потому как ещё множество тонкостей с которыми придётся столкнуться. Буду результаты и траблы сюда писать.